# How to skip and say no match if specific domain exists in regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i want to skip and `preg_match()` return 0 if a string or text contain specific domain for example

```
$var="for see our post visit phyteachers.com |click now";
if(preg_match('(((https?|ftps?)\:\/\/)?((www([0-9]+)?)\.)?.*\.[a-zA-Z0-9](\/)?((?!.*phyteachers\b).*))','$var')==0){
    echo "ok";
}
```

If there is `http://phyteachers.com` or `http://www.phyteachers.com` or `https://www.phyteachers.com` or `https://phyteachers.com` or `www.phyteachers.com` or `phyteachers.com` then return `0`.

Comment: Can't you simplify by using `strpos`? http://php.net/manual/ro/function.strpos.php

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: would you please write code down?

Comment: sorry it's teachers

Comment: maybe sentence or url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My following pattern can probably be refined a bit, but it should serve your purpose.

```
~(?:(?:ht|f)tps?:/{2})?(?:w{3}\d*\.)?(?:phyteachers\.com(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\S+\.[a-z\d]+/?\S*)~
```

https://regex101.com/r/iZ9HRQ/6

For the formal terminology on the components of my pattern, see the demo link.  Otherwise, I'll offer an informal explanation...

```
(?:                 # start optional non-capturing group
    (?:ht|f)tps?    # match http, https, ftp, ftps
    :/{2}           # match colon then two slashes
)?                  # end optional group (none of this HAS to exist)
(?:                 # start optional non-capturing group
    w{3}\d*\.       # match www then zero or more digits, then optiona
)?                  # end optional group
(?:                                # start non-capturing group
    phyteachers\.com(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # abort match if found 
    |                              # or
    \S+\.[a-z\d]+/?\S*             # see the demo, too involved to explain in limited space
)                                  # end non-capturing group
```

Comment: very nice! but it dont capture other link sub category https://regex101.com/r/iZ9HRQ/3

Comment: @MohammadrezaTaheri I have very slightly improved my pattern and added an explanation.  Please use my updated pattern in your project.

Comment: Please show me a link again that exposes the failure

Comment: i do it!:) just add (?:.*\.)* before (?:phyteachers\.com(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\S+\.[a-z\d]+/?\S*)

Comment: sorry another problem!! it capture `phyteachers.com/?id=com.scribd.app.reader0&ref=share` bcz of dots and also take this kind of hash tags `#phyteachers.com`

Comment: @MohammadrezaTaheri This question is becoming an ever growing project.  I think I will have to excuse myself from continued refinements on this pattern.  The subdomains are becoming troublesome for the (*SKIP)(*FAIL) condition.  I will not be able to accommodate for all possible urls/domains/twittertags.  I hope I have given you sufficient traction on this task and if you have further questions on this matter after trying to self-solve, please post a new question.